# Unable to create a nuget package out of a custom control in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, controls

I just created a simple custom control in my xamarin.forms project and want to use the same control as a nuget package in my other projects. After creating the .nupkg file I tested it by adding as a local package in another xamarin forms project.The issue is the package I created is installed,but the contents inside it are not available.. Can anyone help me on resolving this..

Comment: How did you create the .nupkg file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell visual studio to pack the content of a library and generate a nuget package.  This will then include the dll in the package and allow you to access it from other projects.

You can see how to do this in Visual Studio [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli)

Including Xaml files is trickier, but if you can do the UI in code it easier enough.  I created Xamarin.Forms control library on [github](https://github.com/newky2k/DSoft.XamarinForms.Controls) that might be a good place to start.